# Python check if Checkbox in Application is checked

Tags: python, user-interface, pywinauto

Iam currently trying to automate a installing process, which I am doing with **pywinautogui**. I would like to check if a checkbox was checked (which is actually a button), because in some cases the checkbox is alreay checked and it would uncheck it if i pressed it again. is there any way i can figure the state?

```
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'installer.exe')
windowsformswindowappbarad = app[u'Installer']
windowsformswindowappbarad.wait('ready')
windowsformsbuttonappbarad = windowsformswindowappbarad.Button4
#print(checkbox.get_click_state())
windowsformsbuttonappbarad.click()
```

[this is how the Checkbox looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meakl.png)

Edit:

```
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'installer.exe')
windowsformswindowappbarad = app[u'Installer']
windowsformswindowappbarad.set_focus()
windowsformswindowappbarad.wait('ready')
checkbox_object = windowsformswindowappbarad.Button4()

if checkbox_object.get_toggle_state() == 0:
    print("not set")
elif checkbox_object.get_toggle_state() == 1:
    print("ein")
```

Comment: Think you need ```checkbox.get_check_state()```
see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212228/checking-a-checkbox-with-pywinauto-doesnt-work

Comment: i did check this post before but it seems like the value of checkbox.get_check_state() doesnt change. If the checkbox is clicked its "0" and if its not clicked its "0" aswell

Comment: Are you sure you addressing to the right checkbox?

Comment: yeah i located it with swapy so it should be the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below code, you can get the Check box state.

```
Checkbox_object = window_object.wrapper_object()
 if checkbox_object.get_toggle_state() == 0:
            return False
 elif checkbox_object.get_toggle_state() == 1:
            return True
```

Let me know if you face issue .

Below is the code I tried :

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app1 = Application(backend='uia').connect(title="H4)")
app1.H4.set_focus()
checkboxobject=app1.Dialog.CheckBox0
value=checkboxobject.get_toggle_state()
print(value)
```

If value is 0 Check box is not checked , if 1 it is checked

Comment: I tried this, iam realy confused right now because if use the object of the window i get AttributeError: 'DialogWrapper' object has no attribute 'get_toggle_state' if i use the object of the button i get the same Attribute error but with 'ButtenWrapper'

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried with this .

Comment: I believe `Button4()` is the alias name of the UI object . So can you remove the `()` in code and try .

Comment: that worked for me, idk why but Application(backend='uia') solved the problem, thanks

Comment: @HugosBanane please go through https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html this .

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the get_toggle_state(), get_check_state() or is_checked() methods do not work. In these cases the only way is to use:

```
wrapper.legacy_properties()['State']
```

You can retrieve the value of the states with inspect.exe in Legacy|Accessible.State

Comment: checkbox = ButtonWrapper(windowsformsbuttonappbarad.wrapper_object()) checkbox.legacy_properties()['State'] i am not sure how to use it becaucause the ButtonWrapper doesnt have that attribute, could you please explain?

Comment: Did you try to print the value of windowsformsbuttonappbarad.wrapper_object().legacy_properties()['State'] when your checkbox is checked and then not checked?

Comment: yeah but i get this error message AttributeError: 'ButtonWrapper' object has no attribute 'legacy_properties'

Comment: Can you see a Legacy|Accessible.State with inspect.exe ?